# Questions about the surface integral

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

Here's how we get to the formula for the surface integral:

[image]

$$\Delta P_k=\frac{\Delta A_k}{\cos{\gamma}}$$

$$g:\text{ density }$$

$$\text{ Integral }=\sum_k \Delta P_k \cdot g(x_k, y_k, z_k) =\sum_k g(x_k, y_k, z_k) \cdot \frac{\Delta A_k}{\cos{\gamma}}=\iint_S g(x,y,z) \cdot \frac{dA}{\cos{\gamma}}$$

[image]

$$\cos{\gamma}=\frac{|\nabla{F} \cdot \hat{n}|}{|\nabla{F}|}$$

$$\iint_S g(x,y,z) \frac{|\nabla{F}|}{|\nabla{F} \cdot \hat{n}|} dA$$
$$d \sigma=\frac{|\nabla{F}|}{|\nabla{F} \cdot \hat{n}|} dA$$

So $$\iint_R g(x,y,z) d \sigma=\iint_S g(x,y,z) \frac{\nabla{F}}{|\nabla{F} \cdot \hat{n}|} dA$$

---

Could you explain me why at the beginning it is: $\Delta P_k=\frac{\Delta A_k}{\cos{\gamma}}$?

Could you also explain me the first and the last $"="$ of:
$\text{ Integral }=\sum_k \Delta P_k \cdot g(x_k, y_k, z_k) =\sum_k g(x_k, y_k, z_k) \cdot \frac{\Delta A_k}{\cos{\gamma}}=\iint_S g(x,y,z) \cdot \frac{dA}{\cos{\gamma}}$?

At the second picture, why is it: $\hat{n}=\hat{k}$?

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$
[image]

we are integrating on the region of projection of $P_k$ on $xy$ plane,

$(2)$ For the last line of $=$ we just change discrete summation into continuous integral by making $\Delta A_k$ infinitesimal.

$(3)$ $\hat n = \hat k$ because that is the direction of $xy$ plane and we are taking projection of the surface on $xy$ plane. so we take dot product of normal of surface to normal of $xy$ plane.

Added:: in $(2)$ me made a slight error. It's a dot product of vector function and the $P_k$ which has direction along $\frac{\nabla F}{|\nabla F|}$ i.e. unit normal vector.
[image]

See this image
[image]

Comment: $(1):$ I got it!
$$$$
$(2):$ $$\text{Integral}=\sum_k \Delta P_k \cdot g(x_k,y_k,z_k) =\sum_k g(x_k, y_k, z_k) \cdot \frac{\Delta A_k}{\cos{\gamma}}=\iint_S g(x,y,z) \cdot \frac{dA}{\cos{\gamma}}$$
First of all,at the beginning which integral is meant?The integral over the surface $R$?Does the integral over the surface $R$ calculates the area of the surface $R$? Is an other way to calculate the area,taking the sum of the segments $\Delta P_k$?I still haven't understood the last $"="$.
$$$$
$(3):$ I got stuck right now.Why do we take the dot product of normal of surface to normal of $xy$ plane?

Comment: $(2):$ At the first $"="$ do we use the formula of Riemann integral?

Comment: @MaryStar $(2)$ yes, $(3)$ I have updated the answer.

Comment: $(2):$ I got stuck... :/
$$\text{ Integral }=\sum_k \Delta P_k \cdot g(x_k, y_k, z_k) =\sum_k g(x_k, y_k, z_k) \cdot \frac{\Delta A_k}{\cos{\gamma}}=\iint_S g(x,y,z) \cdot \frac{dA}{\cos{\gamma}}$$
That means that the integral of $g$ over the surface $R$, due to Riemann integral, is equal to $\displaystyle{\sum_k \Delta P_k \cdot g(x_k, y_k, z_k) }$. Then we replace $\Delta P_k $ with $\frac{\Delta A_k}{\cos{\gamma}}$. Have I understood it right so far? Then I still haven't understood why this sum is equal to the double integral $\displaystyle{\iint_S g(x,y,z) \cdot \frac{dA}{\cos{\gamma}}}$.

Comment: @MaryStar $dA$ is scalar, but our original $\Delta P_k$ is vector and $|\Delta P_k| = \frac{\Delta A_k}{\cos \gamma}$ there is one thing missing here. That is the direction of the normal of the surface.

Comment: @MaryStar it is missing in your picture too. the direction of $\Delta P_k $ is $ \nabla F$ where is $F$ is surface. Also we make it unit vector

Comment: $$\sum_k g(x_k, y_k, z_k) \cdot \frac{\Delta A_k}{\cos{\gamma}}=\iint_S g(x,y,z) \cdot \frac{dA}{\cos{\gamma}}$$
Do we take the limit at the sum since the parts into those we have partitioned the surface are becoming infinitely many? Has it something to do with the partition of Riemann integral?
$$$$
At the beginning we had that $$\cos{\gamma}=\frac{\Delta A_k}{\Delta P_k}$$
The direction of $\Delta P_k$ is $\nabla{F}$. Is the direction of $\Delta A_k$ equal to $\nabla{F} \cdot \hat{n}$? So $$\cos{\gamma}=\frac{|\nabla{F} \cdot \hat{n}|}{|\nabla{F}|}$$? Or have I understood it wrong??

Comment: @MaryStar yes that's right ... except $\Delta A_k$ is scalar :D and use $\Delta P_k$ as vector, everything will work out (y)

Comment: Since $\Delta A_k$ is scalar, does it have a direction??

Comment: @MaryStar no no ... it only just equal to $dydx$ while $\Delta P_k$ is equal to $|\Delta P_k| \frac{\nabla F}{|\nabla F|}|$

Comment: I thought about it again... 
$$\nabla \overrightarrow{F}: \text{ normal vector of } \Delta P_k$$ 
$$\hat{n}=\hat{k} : \text{ normal vector of } \Delta A_k$$

Comment: The dot product of the vectors $\nabla \overrightarrow{F}$ and $\hat{n}=\hat{k}$:
$$\nabla \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}=|\nabla \overrightarrow{F}| \cdot |\hat{n}|\cdot \cos{\gamma}$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos{\gamma}=\frac{\nabla \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}}{|\nabla \overrightarrow{F}|}$$ Since $\nabla \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}$ is a number it stands that $\nabla \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}=|\nabla \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}|$, right? So $$\cos{\gamma}=\frac{|\nabla \overrightarrow{F} \cdot \hat{n}|}{|\nabla \overrightarrow{F}|}$$

Comment: Is this correct??

Comment: @MaryStar yes that's correct ... just don't use $|.|$ if you wish to take the acute angle between surfaces.

Comment: Do you mean that $\cos{\gamma}$ could be negative, so we cannot take $| \cdot |$, because then a negative number would be equal to a positive number?? Or do I understand it wrong??

Comment: @MaryStar consider the the product of normal vector of sphere and $\vec k$ on the lower hemisphere.

Comment: I haven't got it...Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: @MaryStar see the above image ...